# HTML Navigation positioning

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have pretty simple navigation.
 
Three divs inside a header *(logo, navigation and phone)*.
I want to make them responsive and stretchable whenever user zooms out.
**Example**
http://www.zendrive.com/
Can someone give me a simple CSS example on how to achieve this?

Comment: Right click the navigation at your link, click inspect element.  There is an example of what CSS for that would look like.

Comment: I tried that, but I don't understand the divs there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.header {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    width:  100%;
    height: 60px;
}

.header > * {
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.header .navigation ul {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin:  0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header .navigation li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-icon.png">
    </div>
    <nav class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="phone">555.555.5555</div>
</header>
```

Comment: That is very nice thank you, but items collapse if you zoom in. how can I fix that?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "collapse" and "zoom in"?

Comment: divs just drop on the next lines

Comment: What would you expect to happen if there is not enough space?

Comment: it does not collapse on this website. how can I make my navigation look like that?

Comment: Set a min-width on the header, so it will never collapse. `min-width: 400px;` for example.